# Automate a WADL .XML File for API Console

Tags: xml, web-services, api, web-applications, wadl

I'm building an API console (*with https://apigee.com/togo*) for my web app API.  The Apigee site requires me to upload a XML WADL to show all the methods, etc.

Is there an easy way to automate this process so I don't have to manually create the WADL file? **Let me know if you need any specific info about my API to help answer the question.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're building your API in Java, take a look at Apache CXF, which can generate WADL:
http://cxf.apache.org/

Otherwise, you might try looking at REST Describe:
http://tomayac.de/rest-describe/latest/RestDescribe.html

It's an old project, but it might help jumpstart your WADL creation.

You probably already know this last tip, but if you are writing your WADL by hand, be sure to look at the sample WADL provided as part of Apigee To-Go, since it is fairly well commented.

We (I work at Apigee) are exploring ideas about how to make the API description process less painful than having to create a WADL, but for today, those are the best suggestions I can make.

Hope that helps,

Marsh

Comment: Is there any work going on with this? I have an app  built using Jerser with a pretty extensive WADL that I want to import into apigee. 

I can not hand-coded it, it is not feasable. Is there a Doclet generator that I can use that overcomes these problems? Can I annotate my Java code with the apigee-specific tags and generate the WADL so that apigee can import my api?